# How to combine cellcolor and rotated text in a table correctly?

Tags: tables, cellcolor

I try to create a table that has a width corresponding to `1.2\linewidth`, colored cells and rotated text in columns 4 to 9. I have problems with coloring the cells containing the rotated text and to stretch the table over `1.2\linewidth` of the page. Can you help me please?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{14,101,123}
\definecolor{mybrightblue}{RGB}{0,176,240}
\definecolor{mybrightgreen}{RGB}{197,224,180}
\definecolor{mybrightorange}{RGB}{248,203,173}
\definecolor{mybrightred}{RGB}{255,109,109}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\STAB}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\cellcolor{mybrightblue}#1            

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular*}{1.2\linewidth}{|l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|l|l|@{}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{ID}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Test}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Test Text}} & 
    \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Inspection Criteria}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{New}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Comment}} \\ \cline{4-9}
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Description}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\cellcolor{mybrightblue}\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~~Criteria 1~~}}} &    
    \multirow{3}{*}{\cellcolor{mybrightblue}\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 2}}} &
    \multirow{3}{*}{\cellcolor{mybrightblue}\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 3}}} &
    \multirow{3}{*}{\cellcolor{mybrightblue}\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 4}}} & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\cellcolor{mybrightblue}\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 5}}} &
    \multirow[c]{3}{*}{\cellcolor{mybrightblue}\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 6}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Workflow}} & \cellcolor{mydarkblue} \\
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue} & \multirow[t]{2}{*}{\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{Name}} & \cellcolor{mydarkblue} & & & & & & & \cellcolor{mydarkblue}\textbf{State} & \cellcolor{mydarkblue} \\
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue} & \cellcolor{mydarkblue} & \cellcolor{mydarkblue} & & & & & & & \cellcolor{mydarkblue} & \cellcolor{mydarkblue} \\ \hline 

    T-123 & Test Text 1 & Description 1 & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} APPROVED & \\ \hline
    T-124 & Test Text 2 & Description 2 & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightred} NOK & \cellcolor{mybrightorange} PARTLY & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightgreen} OK & \cellcolor{mybrightred} NOK & \cellcolor{mybrightred} REJECTED & \\ \hline
    & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

My problem looks like this:
[image]

The cells with the criteria should be filled completely and the cells containing the words OK, PARTLY, NOK, APPROVED, REJECTED should be rotated like the criteria cells. In addition, the table should has a width of `1.2\linewidth`. The columns for the criteria should have equal width. If possible, columns 1, 2, 3 and 11 should be multiple line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution. Much simpler code that your MWE. In particular, the request that the table had to be wider than the line width, was challenging. Of cause, you will have the usual problem when combining lines and colours in tables. Lines are overwritten by the colours.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}

\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{14,101,123}
\definecolor{mybrightblue}{RGB}{0,176,240}
\definecolor{mybrightgreen}{RGB}{197,224,180}
\definecolor{mybrightorange}{RGB}{248,203,173}
\definecolor{mybrightred}{RGB}{255,109,109}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(0.095\linewidth-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(0.15\linewidth-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(0.05\linewidth-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))}}


\begin{document}

\noindent Blindtext. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. Which is just a text to see the text line.

\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.1\linewidth}{-0.1\linewidth}

\noindent Blindtext. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. Which is just a text to see the text line.
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}

\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|F|P|P|Q|Q|Q|Q|Q|Q|P|P|}
\hline
    \rowcolor{mydarkblue}
    \bfseries ID & 
    \bfseries Test & 
    \bfseries Test Text & 
    \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries Inspection Criteria} & 
    \bfseries New &
    \bfseries Comment
\\\cline{4-9}
    \rowcolor{mybrightblue}
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue}&
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue}\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\bfseries Text\\ \cellcolor{mydarkblue}Name\end{tabular}
&
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue}\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\bfseries Description\\\cellcolor{mydarkblue}~\end{tabular}&
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Criteria 1} &    
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Criteria 2} &
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Criteria 3} &
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Criteria 4} & 
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Criteria 5} &
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~Criteria 6} &
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue}\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\cellcolor{mydarkblue}\bfseries Workflow\\ \cellcolor{mydarkblue}State \end{tabular}&
    \cellcolor{mydarkblue}
\\\hline 
    T-123 & 
    Test Text 1 &
    Description 1 &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~APPROVED~} &
\\ \hline
    T-124 &
    Test Text 2 &
    Description 2 &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}&
    \cellcolor{mybrightred}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NOK}&
    \cellcolor{mybrightorange}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{PARTLY} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightgreen}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightred}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NOK} &
    \cellcolor{mybrightred}\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{~REJECTED~} &
\\ \hline
    & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

And for the sake of completeness, here is a `calstable`, using the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, cals, xcolor}
\usepackage{changepage}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{14,101,123}
\definecolor{mybrightblue}{RGB}{0,176,240}
\definecolor{mybrightgreen}{RGB}{197,224,180}
\definecolor{mybrightorange}{RGB}{248,203,173}
\definecolor{mybrightred}{RGB}{255,109,109}

\begin{document}

\noindent Blindtext. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. Which is just a text to see the text line.

\begin{calstable}[c]

% Defining 11 column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*1\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*1\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*1\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*1\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*1\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*1\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(1.2\columnwidth/20)*3\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills 120% of the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}             % Define cals@bgcolor to empty

\def\dblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty      % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{mydarkblue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\bblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty      % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{mybrightblue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\bgreen{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{mybrightgreen}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\bred{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty   % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{mybrightred}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\borange{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty    % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{mybrightorange}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\makeatother

\thead{\small\bfseries
\brow 
    \dblue\alignL\nc{tlr}
    \alignL\nc{tlr}
    \alignL\nc{tlr}
    \alignC\nc{ltb}
    \alignC\nc{tb}
    \alignC\nc{tb}
    \alignC\nc{tb}
    \alignC\nc{tb}
    \alignC\nc{rtb}\sc{Inspection Criteria}
    \alignL\nc{tlr}
    \alignL\nc{tlr}
\erow
\brow 
    \alignL\nc{blr}\sc{ID}
    \alignL\nc{blr}\sc{Test\par Text\par Name}
    \alignL\nc{blr}\sc{Test Text\par Description}\dblue
    \bblue\alignC\cell{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 1}}
    \alignC\cell{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 2}}
    \alignC\cell{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 3}}
    \alignC\cell{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 4}}
    \alignC\cell{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 5}}
    \alignC\cell{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria 6}}\bblue
    \dblue\alignL\nc{blr}\sc{New\par Workflow\par State}
    \alignL\nc{blr}\sc{Comment}\bblue
\erow
\mdseries}
\brow 
    \alignL\cell{T-123}
    \alignL\cell{Test Text 1}
    \alignL\cell{Description 1}
    \bgreen\alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}
    \alignL\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{APPROVED}}\bgreen
    \alignL\cell{}
\erow
\brow 
    \alignL\cell{T-124}
    \alignL\cell{Test Text 2}
    \alignL\cell{Description 2}
    \bgreen\alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}\bgreen
    \bred\alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NOK}}\bred
    \borange\alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{PARTLY}}\borange
    \bgreen\alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{OK}}\bgreen
    \bred\alignC\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{NOK}}
    \alignL\cell{\vfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{REJECTED}}\bred
    \alignL\cell{}
\erow
\brow 
    \alignL\cell{T-125}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \alignL\cell{}
\erow
\brow 
    \alignL\cell{T126}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \alignL\cell{}
    \alignL\cell{}
\erow
\end{calstable}

\end{document}
```